# Further help needed with Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I recently [asked for and received help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612332/) regarding a Java regular expression that would match a string containing a maximum of two asterisks, which could be the first or last character, or both. This was the answer I accepted:

```
^\\*?[^*]+\\*?$
```

Naturally, the requirements have now changed and I need to further constrain the string such that it can only contain either lower or upper case letters, spaces or the asterisk wildcard character. No numbers or punctuation (other than `*`) are allowed. The constraints on the wildcard positioning remain as described above.

So these strings would be matched:

```
foo
f oo
*Foo
FOO *
*foo*
*F o o*
```

And these strings would not:

```
*
**
**foo
*f*oo
1
*1
_
foo1*
_foo
%foo^
```

I have spent ages trying to work this out and haven't been able to, even using [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/). I don't really like asking such a specific question on Stack Overflow, but I just can't get to the solution on my own.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
^\\*?[a-zA-Z ]+\\*?$
```

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to match underscores for some reason.

Comment: @John Topley: `-` is hyphen. check your regex.

Comment: @John Topley, don't think so - can you give an example

Comment: @Peter Ivanov The problem was when I copied and pasted your regex with the lower case `z` typo before you edited your answer! All OK now, thanks. And damn, I'm sure I'd already tried your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If regex must match all Unicode letters: `^\*?[\p{L} ]+\*?$`